# JUnit test on null objects, strings, boolean etc

Tags: java, junit

How do I implement a JUnit test for null objects etc? It does not need to test for null objects however, strings etc is also acceptable. Have looked at the following links but I still do not get it.

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dk0Lz1riYe4
- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html

If given the following method, how do i do so, specifically & simply please?

```
public int queryTime(String examSession){ //returns time of specific the exam session
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<es.size();i++){
        if (es.get(i).getid().equals(examSession)) //if id matches, return time
            return es.get(i).getTimeOfExam();
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I have the following test case:

```
public class JTest1 
{
    private entity.Module mod;
    private String input = null;

@Test
public void test()
{
    //test null obj
    assertNull (mod.queryTime(input));      
}
```

}

Comment: What do you want to test? What are your expectations?

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry, for example in the code above, how do I test if no string input is entered? if you like, i can paste my attempt?

Comment: What does _no string input is entered_ mean? You need to invoke the method with whatever argument corresponds to that explanation. You then need to give your expectations.

Comment: I have done an edit. pls kindly point out what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you want to unit test `queryTime()` method.
I am not sure what you want to test as queryTime() never returns `null`
You need to test two cases, since there are two possible return values(none of which is `null`)

So, if I were to write these test, I would write

```
@Test
public shoudReturnQueryTimeGivenValidExamSession(){
    Module mod = new Module() ; 
    String input = "some_string";
    Integer result = 1;//Some integer

    // Set the expectations
    Object object = Mock(Object.class) ; // This should be class(in place of object) of type es
    Object object1 = Mock(Object.class) ; // This should be class of what es.get(1) returns. I assume es is a list of somethings and es.get(1) returns an object of your custom class. So In prev line, Object -> ArrayList, this line Object -> YourCustomObject
    when(object.get(1)).thenReturn(object1); 
    when(object1.getid()).thenReturn(input);
    when(object1.getTimeOfExam()).thenReturn(result);

    //Make the call
   Integer actualResult = mod.queryTime(input);

    //Verify
   assertEquals(result, actualResult);
}
```

Similarly you need to test one more case where the output was -1.

Comment: thank you! but i will keep it v simple as in for my case, have learnt a lot! :)